# Use trigger as assertion in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

I have a database and a few tables in MySql. I am trying to implement an Oracle assertion in MySQL using `CREATE TRIGGER`. I am not sure if I used the proper syntax.

This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure why it's wrong.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_review_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON review
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.paper = IF((SELECT * FROM paper P WHERE 3 <>(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM review R
    WHERE R.paperid = P.paperid)
);
```

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE paper(
    paperid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    abstract VARCHAR(250),
    pdf VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY(paperid)
);

CREATE TABLE author(
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    affiliation VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY(email)
);

CREATE TABLE writePaper(
    paperid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email VARCHAR(100),
    paper_order INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(paperid, email),
    FOREIGN KEY(paperid) REFERENCES paper(paperid),
    FOREIGN KEY(email) REFERENCES author(email)
);

CREATE TABLE pcmember(
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(email)
);

CREATE TABLE review(
    reportid INT UNSIGNED,
    sdate DATE,
    comment VARCHAR(250),
    recommendation CHAR(1),
    paperid INT UNSIGNED,
    email VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY(paperid, email),
    FOREIGN KEY(paperid) REFERENCES paper(paperid),
    FOREIGN KEY(email) REFERENCES pcmember(email)
);
```

Here are the assertions I am trying to implement from Oracle SQL code to MySQL SQL code:

```
CREATE ASSERTION assert
CHECK NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM paper P WHERE 3 <>(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM review R
    WHERE R.paperid = P.paperid)
);

CREATE ASSERTION atmostfivepapers
CHECK NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM pcmember P WHERE 5 <
    ( SELECT *
    FROM review R
    WHERE R.email = P.email
    )
);
```

Comment: "This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure why it's wrong." You sure you are using MySQL.. MySQL never implemented `CREATE ASSERTION`

Comment: I know, I am trying to convert that into MySQL syntax (that is Oracle SQL code)

Comment: i changed the question a bit so it's more clear and added a oracle tag.. Because it looked like you was trying to execute the `CREATE ASSERTION` SQL code directly on a MySQL server.. A leak of coffee also might have be a reason i misreaded it or misunderstood it.

Comment: "from Oracle SQL"? I wasn't aware that Oracle Database implemented `CREATE ASSERTION` either. What version of Oracle did you see that in?

Comment: I'm not sure, I only recently learned this in my databases class and we were told in Oracle you can create assertions. I'm stuck as to how I would do something like this in MySQL. @mathguy

Comment: Either your teacher told you wrong or you misunderstood what they said. Oracle does not (yet) support CREATE ASSERTION. However, there is a major push to get that support. [Find out more](https://community.oracle.com/ideas/13028).